# How can I query UTC-dates for the client's current day?

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-core, utc

My goal is to query the database for entries of the current day. Let's say the user saves a row with a time of '2021-01-27 01:00' and one with '2021-01-27 00:59'. The time zone is GMT+1 so it will be stored in the database in UTC like this:

row1: '2021-01-27T 00:00Z'

row2: '2021-01-26T 23:59Z'

How can I query for rows of the 27th of January 2021 (selectedUtcDate), from the view of the client / client?

The following will only return one entry:

```
.Where(row => row.Date == selectedUtcDate)
```

Do I have to use a range to get all entries of the same date?

```
.Where(row => row.Date >= selectedUtcDate && row.Date < selectedUtcDate.AddDays(1))
```

Or is this even automatically resolved by entity framework?

Comment: You'll need to know the offsets for the time zone for that date, then you can create two dates; one for the start of the day and one for the end of the day. Then query for all records between those two DateTime values.

Comment: Presumably you meant `AddHours(24)`. Is `currentUtcDate` and `selectedUtcDate` the same thing?

Comment: Like @HereticMonkey already mentioned, you need the offset. But you won't need the offset of the stored date, because you know it is UTC and therefore it's the offset +00:00. What you need is the offset of the client (users offset). If you know the users offset you can add it to the stored date and you got the stored date in the clients time which is comparable.

Comment: It is generally preferred to stores dates and times as UTC because it's generally easier to convert these back to a specific timezone. However, if it's important that you know what timezone the date belongs to, you'll have to also store that. It could be as simple as storing the offset (in hours) of the time to UTC or store the actual timezone info if you're going to be doing calculations, as daylight saving info ___WILL___ become an issue.

Comment: What I still don't understand is why DateTime.UtcNow.Date is '2021-01-27T 00:00Z' and not '2021-01-26T 23:00Z' for GMT+1. If it was the second one, then the query with the date range should actually work no matter the time zone or daylight saving, right?

Comment: UTC is always UTC irrespective of the current timezone

Answer (score 1):

This has nothing to do with a database. The problem is, that the 24 hours or January 27th in Beijing are not the same 24 hours in Greenwich.

Internally, you use UTC. If somewhere on a computer in Beijing a date in local time is known, you know the start DateTime of that day and the start DateTime of the next day. After that you can convert these DateTime value to UTC:

```
DateTime localDay = FetchDateInLocalTime();  // The day in Beijing
DateTime utcDayStartTime = localDay.Date.ToUniversalTime;
DateTime utcNextDayStartTime = utcDayStartTime.AddDays(+1);
```

Now comes the database part:

```
var result = dbContext.Orders.Where(order => utcDayStartTime <= order.Date
                                          && order.Date < utNextDayStartTime);
```

Simple comme bonjour!

Answer (score 0):

So to answer the original question with help of the comments:

- Yes you have to use a range to query dates like this.
- And of course you need to use the client's local date converted to utc (or the offset) as Harald Coppoolse mentioned.